# I cannot enable sa account

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, account

I dont have users in sysadmin except [sa] user

unfortunately, I logged in as [sa] user and disabled it

then I cant enable it, what I can do to enable it again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to use `sqlcmd.exe` with `Windows Authentication (Specify the -E flag)` and renable the account:

Open up command prompt and navigate to the `SQL Directory` and use `sqlcmd.exe -S server -E`

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
GO
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Answer (score 14):

login with windows authentication and select server properties and go to security tab check the bubble SQL server and windows authentication **click ok**.

or

**run below query**

```
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD='AnyStronG@#Passw)e', CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
GO
```

Ref:- [Enable Sa Login](http://microsoft-sql-ssis.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-to-enable-sa-user-name-in-sql-server.html)

Comment: Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20161005170441/http://www.microsoft-sql-ssis.com/2015/09/how-to-enable-sa-user-name-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 10):

1. Launch SQL Server Configuration Manager (as local machine Administrator)
2. Select SQL Server Services -> SQL Server Service on the right side
3. Right-Click on it -> Properties -> Advanced Tab
4. Into "Startup Parameters" string add ';-m' to the end of string -> This will bring SQL server to 'single user mode' in which local machine Admins have super-user rights.
5. Restart service in order Startup Parameters to take effect.
6. Login via SQL Server Management Studio using Windows Authentication as local machine Administrator -> now it has super-user preferences and allows you to change everything.

Answer (score 2):

Check if both Windows and mixed authentication is enabled on the server properties > Security

.[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31091001)